# I'm trying to create a GlobalFilter to validate an RSA token but it's giving an error

Tags: spring-boot, rsa

I'm trying to create a GlobalFilter to validate an RSA token but it's giving an error:

> No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String]
> to type [java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey]

my component LoggingGlobalPreFilter.java:

```
@Component
public class LoggingGlobalPreFilter implements GlobalFilter {

  final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingGlobalPreFilter.class);
  private RsaKeyPropreties Rsakeys;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
      logger.info("Pre-Filter executed");
    
      String requestPath = exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();
      logger.info("Request path = " + requestPath);
      
      HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
      Set<String> headerNames = headers.keySet();

      headerNames.forEach((header) -> {
          if(header.equals("Authorization")){
            SignedJWT sign;
            try {
              
              String token = headers.get(header).toString();
              if (token == null) {
                token="";
              }
              
              sign = SignedJWT.parse(token);
              JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(Rsakeys.publickey());
              logger.info(header + " " + sign.verify(verifier));

            } catch (ParseException | JOSEException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
          }
          
      });

      return chain.filter(exchange);
  }

 
}
```

My application class RoutingApplication.java:

```
EnableConfigurationProperties(RsaKeyPropreties.class)
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class RoutingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Rsa Class RsaKeyPropreties.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa")
public record RsaKeyPropreties(RSAPublicKey publickey,RSAPrivateKey privatekey) {
    
}
```

My application.properties:

```
rsa.publickey=classpath:routing/public.pem
rsa.privatekey=classpath:routing/private.pem
```

My files rsa:
[image]

Does anyone know a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get through application.properties so I did some tests and got it by taking the path of plubic.em and opening the file and converting it to RSAPublicKey. below is the solution:

class RsaKeyPropreties:

```
package com.example.routing.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class RsaKeyPropreties{

    private String charKey;

    public String getPublicKey(){
        return this.charKey;
    }

    public void readResourceFile() {
        Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/routing/public.pem");
        try {
            this.charKey = Files.readAllLines(path).toString();
            this.charKey = StringUtils.removeEnd(this.charKey , ", -----END PUBLIC KEY-----]")
            .replace("[-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----, ","").replace(", ","");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    
}
```

class LoggingGlobalPreFilter:

```
package com.example.routing.components;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.text.ParseException;
import com.example.routing.config.RsaKeyPropreties;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSASSAVerifier;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class LoggingGlobalPreFilter implements GlobalFilter {

  final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingGlobalPreFilter.class);
  
  private RsaKeyPropreties Rsakeys = new RsaKeyPropreties();

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
      logger.info("Pre-Filter executed");
    
      String requestPath = exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString();
      logger.info("Request path = " + requestPath);
      
      HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
      Set<String> headerNames = headers.keySet();

      headerNames.forEach((header) -> {
          if(header.equals("Authorization")){
            String token = StringUtils.removeEnd(headers.get(header).toString(), "]")
            .replace("[Bearer ","");

            SignedJWT sign;
            Rsakeys.readResourceFile();

            try {
              if (token == null) {
                token="";
              }

              sign = SignedJWT.parse(token);
              byte[] publicBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Rsakeys.getPublicKey());
              X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
              KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
              PublicKey publickey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
             

              JWSVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier((RSAPublicKey) publickey);

              if(sign.verify(verifier)){
                logger.info("Valido");
              }else{
                logger.info("invalido");
              }
              

            } catch (ParseException | JOSEException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
          }
          
      });

      return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution post it